# Provide the ability to change API search tag constraint

Tags: feature-request, api

There was a feature request (or maybe it was an implementation) recently that asked for searches containing tags to use an OR constraint, rather than require all tags searched to be on the question.

I'd like to ask for something similar in the API, for the /2.2/search route's `tagged` parameter - but instead of enforcing an OR constraint, can we be allowed to choose whether it's OR or AND?

Comment: It was actually the other way around